# Distributive property of Ket over addition

Tags: quantum-state

If:

$$|a> = \binom{-4i}{2} $$

$$|b> = \binom{1}{-1+i} $$

Then what will the value of $$|a + b> $$ be?

That is, is addition distributive over the ket notation?

Comment: What does $| a + b \rangle$ even mean? How are you defining it?

Comment: I came across this question in a book, and wasn't sure what exactly this notation meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, writing something like $\lvert a+b\rangle$ does not make sense (is not defined). Here's a quote from the Wiki page on bra-ket notation:

> Symbols, letters, numbers, or even words—whatever serves as a convenient label—can be used as the label inside a ket, with the $\lvert\rangle$ making clear that the label indicates a vector in vector space. In other words, the symbol $\lvert A\rangle$ has a specific and universal mathematical meaning, while just the "$A$" by itself does not. For example, $\lvert 1\rangle + \lvert 2\rangle$ is not necessarily equal to $\lvert 3\rangle$. Nevertheless, for convenience, there is usually some logical scheme behind the labels inside kets, such as the common practice of labeling energy eigenkets in quantum mechanics through a listing of their quantum numbers.

What we put inside of the $\lvert \rangle$ is, essentially, just a name for a vector, and this name may be a number, like $\lvert 0\rangle$ (which we use to denote the first standard basis vector of $\mathbb C^2$), or it could be some other symbol like $\lvert +\rangle$ (used to denote the first element of the Hadamard basis) or $\lvert \uparrow\rangle, \lvert\downarrow\rangle$ (used to denote a "spin up" or "spin down" state). In the latter case, it becomes more clear that what you're asking is not really well-defined. What would $\uparrow + \downarrow$ even mean?

Comment: Got it! This question was given in a book as an exercise, I am guessing it was a misprint. Thanks for this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If what the book meant was |a> + |b>; I believe it would just be element-wise addition. i.e. |a>+|b> = \begin{bmatrix}a_1+b_1\\a_2+b_2\end{bmatrix}

As well, to be more explicit, $$|0> + |1>= \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$